# How to setup CF9 with IIS7 (multiple instance, virtual hosting by hostname)

Tags: iis, iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm used to setting up CF9 (Dev edition) on my Windows machine, using Apache.  I would like to try using IIS7 since that comes with Win7 Pro.  What are the steps to set it up so that I can have:

- www.siteA.dev
- www.siteB.dev

Both of these point to `127.0.0.1` via the windows host file.  I would like siteA.dev and siteB.dev to use 2 different CF instances. I've already installed CF9 dev edition with the 2nd option.  What should I do next?

- Do I need to use the IIS manager, or is the CF's Web Server Config tool all I need?
- Where do I enter data into IIS, like vhost in Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install different instances, and then configure them to use your IIS website.

I explain [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090926232950/http://www.placona.co.uk:80/blog/post.cfm/creating-new-coldfusion-8-instances-the-easy-way) how to do it (it's on Cf8, but the process should be exactly the same).

After the instances are created, it's as simple as going to c:\jrun4\bin\wsconfig (or wherever you wsconfig is), and relating the existing ColdFusion instance with the IIS website.

The screen looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [adobe.com](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/multi_instances/fig12.gif))</sub>

Having it done, you will be able to access your new instances via the addresses created via hosts file.

Hope this helps you Henry.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

Answering your question about the IIS here.

Simply create the IIS website. Then go to properties, and click advanced, and add a nerw hosts header as below:

[alt text http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/8720/iis.jpg](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/8720/iis.jpg)

On the host header value, simply add the name you want, i.e. mywebsite1.dev.

Now, go to hosts file, and add an entry with the same value pointing to 127.0.0.1

After that, simply follow the steps I already mentioned above for the WSCONFIG.

Comment: IIS Web Site: still points to "Default Web Site" on your screenshot.  How do I set up a new website that responds only to siteA.dev and another one that responds only to siteB.dev? Thx.

Comment: Create the website as you would normally via IIS, after you have done that, go to the wsconfig, and "relate" your website with your application. On the hosts file, simply do:

siteA.dev 127.0.0.1
siteB.dev 127.0.0.1

And that's all

Comment: Let's skip CF for a moment, I think I still don't know where to set up IIS so that WebsiteA only responds to siteA.dev.  Thx...